# javascript worker between page loads

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

I have the following code

```
w = new Worker('<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+"assets/js/web_worker.js");
w.postMessage({base_url:BASE_URL,site_url:SITE_URL});
```

This runs on each page load and the worker could take awhile to run task.

1. Will the worker continue to run if I navigate away from page after I start it?
2. It seems the worker will start each page load regardless if it is finished. How do a see if the worker is running and NOT start another worker?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Will the worker continue to run if I navigate away from page after I start it?

No, as soon as the context from which it has been generated has been killed, the Worker gets killed too.

> 2. It seems the worker will start each page load regardless if it is finished. How do a see if the worker is running and NOT start another worker?

Indeed, a new Worker will start every time, but there won't be an other worker running as per one.

---

That is, if we talk about dedicated Workers.

A Shared-Worker would survive a page reload **if an other page keeps it active during the reload**.

And while that would be a misuse, a Service-Worker would definitely survive.

Actually the best might have been to start a Shared-Worker from a Service-Worker, but I think this is still not doable, despite [active discussions](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/411).

Comment: I don't think shared workers work in Safari. I need something that is cross-platform so I think I regular worker in my only option?